# Change views when iPhone is rotated?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

How would I have one view up when the iPhone is in a standard 'portrait' orientation, and switch to a different view (say a graph or something) when rotated to a landscape orientation and visa versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable orientation for that view (assuming that the first view is landscape)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)||(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); }
```

Then add this to the viewDidAppear

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
 object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

And add this method somewhere

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIDevice * device = note.object;
    switch(device.orientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            // Present View Controller here
            break;
        default:
            break;
    };
}
```

And on the other view do the same but backwards with a dismiss for landscape instead of the present for portrait.

Dont forget to unregister for the notifications.

(alternatively use a navigation view with both controls but without the bar and simply show the one you want depending on the orientation using)

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Comment: Where would i put the code to unregister for notifcations? in the viewDidDisapear?

Comment: yup, or in the willdissapear. i forgot to mention that this approach is meant for when you get a complex layout its a bit harder to manage but it should not interfere with your usual app rotation behavior.

Comment: the only code i need to use to unregister notifications is `[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];` right?

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

Answer (score 1):

First read how UIViewControllers work:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Then, in your UIViewController subclass, take advantage of `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` to change out your views.

e.g.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
    // if portrait
    [self.landscapeView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:self.portraitView];

    // if landscape
    [self.portraitView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:self.landscapeView];
}
```

And add in the appropriate `if` statement or `switch` case to determine which to do.