# Is it possible to change views when the device is rotated?

Tags: ios

When the device is in portrait mode, I want to show text details about a graph, and when the user rotates it, I want my `UIWebView` to take up the full screen. This functionality can be seen in the iOS Stock app. When you are portrait, you can view all your stocks, and when the app is landscape, the full size graph is shown. How do i do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093010/change-views-when-iphone-is-rotated?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UIViewController sub-class override `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to replace the view contents with the view contents for the appropriate destination orientation.  I'd suggest using `[UIView transitionFromView:toView:...]` for smoother animations.